# Can i show GIF images in UIImageView in IOS10?

Tags: git, uiimageview, xcode8, ios10

i have used gif image to show in UIImageView but there are showing only static images.what is the reason behined it i don't know.

so somebody please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  recommend you to use [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif).

Import the Gif.swift in your project and do the following:

```
// Returns an animated UIImage
let jeremyGif = UIImage.gifWithName("jeremy")

// Use the UIImage in your UIImageView
let imageView = UIImageView(image: jeremyGif)
```

For Objective c You can use this [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)

Comment: sorry but i want answer in objective-c .

Comment: for objective C Check my Answer i have updated my answer